# Thinking about Purim Torah in the bathroom

Tags: halacha, torah-study, purim, bathroom, humor

It is not permitted to think about Torah in the bathroom regularly, but what about Purim Torah, which is certainly not real Torah study, but still often refers to actual Torah?

One might think that it would be forbidden because the person would still be thinking about the actual texts. On the other hand, one might think that it would be permitted because the person is not actually learning in the bathroom.

I do not know if it is as simple as this, but the distinction that I made in the comments below is that this comes down to the specifics of what one is normally not allowed to do in the bathroom. Is it just thinking about the words that is forbidden, or is it actually thinking about real learning that is forbidden?  Perhaps neither of these is correct or sufficient to answer the question.

Comment: I did not tag this question as Purim Torah because I am looking for real answers. I suppose this question could also be asked in a Purim-Torah fashion.

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/26174/if-i-am-obligated-to-be-drunk-all-the-time-how-is-purim-different#comment59036_26183

Comment: @DoubleAA, I'd say that the last clause in the question is a good a source for that point as a comment from me.

Comment: Being that you will be thinking about psukim, gemaros, etc, why do you think there would be a heter?

Comment: @Shraga I guess it depends on the reason for not being allowed to think about it in the first place. Is it actual learning that you shouldn't think about, or are you not even allowed to think about the words?

Comment: @Daniel, I encourage you to include as much of your thoughts to date on this matter as you can into the question.

Comment: @IsaacMoses, I have edited the question accordingly.

Comment: You do have to think of real תורה to twist into פורים תורה, so wouldn't that make the איסור apply?

Comment: Could this possibly be a safek on a safek?

Answer (score 3):

No it is assur, for through trying to come up with shtus you will inevitably run through actual Torah in your mind. This is so even if you wanted to read heretical books in the bathroom which of course has no kedusha, yet since you will inevitably think of torah it is prohibited.

Comment: Makes sense !!!