# Is it permissible to think about a future Mi Yodeya question while you're in the bathroom?

Tags: halacha, torah-study, bathroom

I understand that you should not be thinking about Torah while in the bathroom. I assume that existing Mi Yodeya questions would be considered Divrei Torah, b/c people have been discussing Torah ideas (for MOST of the questions, that is.)

However, a question that has not yet been posted, maybe is NOT in the category of "Divrei Torah". After all, the question might be rejected, it may be off-topic, etc. So, maybe it is permissible?

Comment: Questions that involve Torah can still be off-topic. If you are thinking about Torah, you are thinking about Torah.

Comment: @Fred - Good point. I'm going to ponder over this very question, now ... while I go to the bathroom. I may have to edit or delete it :-(

Comment: Wait, were you in the bathroom when you thought of this question?

Answer (score 1):

If it involves Torah in any way, shape, or form, it's assur. See [this question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/26225/thinking-about-purim-torah-in-the-bathroom?rq=1) about Purim Torah.