# Nevuah or just a dream

Tags: nevua-prophecy, samuel-shmuel-book-of, dream

How would we know if we "dreamed" of Hashem talking to us, but were actually getting Nevuah? 
Even Shmuel was confused the first time...in fact, he also lived in a  time when Nevuah had been withheld for a while, like ours.

Shmuel 1, Chapter 3:

א. וְהַנַּעַר שְׁמוּאֵל מְשָׁרֵת אֶת יְהֹוָה לִפְנֵי עֵלִי וּדְבַר יְהֹוָה הָיָה יָקָר בַּיָּמִים הָהֵם אֵין חָזוֹן נִפְרָץ:
ב. וַיְהִי בַּיּוֹם הַהוּא וְעֵלִי שֹׁכֵב בִּמְקוֹמוֹ וְעֵינָיו הֵחֵלּוּ כֵהוֹת לֹא יוּכַל לִרְאוֹת:
    ג. וְנֵר אֱלֹהִים טֶרֶם יִכְבֶּה וּשְׁמוּאֵל שֹׁכֵב בְּהֵיכַל יְהֹוָה אֲשֶׁר שָׁם אֲרוֹן אֱלֹהִים:
    ד. וַיִּקְרָא יְהֹוָה אֶל שְׁמוּאֵל וַיֹּאמֶר הִנֵּנִי:
        ה. וַיָּרָץ אֶל עֵלִי וַיֹּאמֶר הִנְּנִי כִּי קָרָאתָ לִּי וַיֹּאמֶר לֹא קָרָאתִי שׁוּב שְׁכָב וַיֵּלֶךְ וַיִּשְׁכָּב:
    ו. וַיֹּסֶף יְהֹוָה קְרֹא עוֹד שְׁמוּאֵל וַיָּקָם שְׁמוּאֵל וַיֵּלֶךְ אֶל עֵלִי וַיֹּאמֶר הִנְנִי כִּי קָרָאתָ לִי וַיֹּאמֶר לֹא קָרָאתִי בְנִי שׁוּב שְׁכָב:
        ז. וּשְׁמוּאֵל טֶרֶם יָדַע אֶת יְהֹוָה וְטֶרֶם יִגָּלֶה אֵלָיו דְּבַר יְהֹוָה:
        ח. וַיֹּסֶף יְהֹוָה קְרֹא שְׁמוּאֵל בַּשְּׁלִישִׁת וַיָּקָם וַיֵּלֶךְ אֶל עֵלִי וַיֹּאמֶר הִנְנִי כִּי קָרָאתָ לִי וַיָּבֶן עֵלִי כִּי יְהֹוָה קֹרֵא לַנָּעַר:
    ט. וַיֹּאמֶר עֵלִי לִשְׁמוּאֵל לֵךְ שְׁכָב וְהָיָה אִם יִקְרָא אֵלֶיךָ וְאָמַרְתָּ דַּבֵּר יְהֹוָה כִּי שֹׁמֵעַ עַבְדֶּךָ וַיֵּלֶךְ שְׁמוּאֵל וַיִּשְׁכַּב בִּמְקוֹמוֹ:

Comment: ha!  related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/41003/1498

Comment: I feel like the Rambam discusses this in Yesodei Hatorah

Comment: Related (duplicate?): http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/11546/472

Comment: @MonicaCellio looks like a duplicate question to me. Interesting that they got such different answers, though, so I don't know....

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Basically the answer would be the same as an answer to a question how do we distinguish reality from a dream. The realness of a prophecy would be overwhelming.

Rabeinu Crescas addresses this question in his book "Ohr Hashem" (Maamar 2, Rule 4, Ch. 3).

> וזה, שכמו שיש יתרון להרגש החוש על הרגש הדמיון, שבעבורו יודע המרגיש והוא ער, שאיננו מרגיש בדמיון לבד, רצוני לומר בחלום; כן יש יתרון להרגש הדמיון הנבואיי, ואם הוא חלום, לדמיון הבלתי נבואיי. והוא האות תאמתי אשר יודע לנביא היותו מנבא, ואם היה חולם.

---

> The same difference that exists between sense and imagination that tells the person he is awake and not only imagining in a dream, this same difference exists between prophetic imagination even if it is in a dream and a non prophetic imagination. And this is a true sign that tells the prophet that he is prophesying even in a dream.

Comment: And then I suppose that fits with Shmuel too. He didn't think he might have been dreaming, he thought the voice was from REALITY.

Answer (score 8):

Perhaps you wouldn't know, without someone to educate you.

Ramchal, Derech Hashem, 3:4:3:

> הנה אפשר שיגיע גילוי ממנו ית' אל אדם והוא לא יכיר בו כמו שיכיר הנביא אלא יחשבהו בא מן המורגשות עד שיגבר עליו השפע הנבואיי ואז יכיר הענין כמות שהוא באמת. ומן המין הזה היתה קריאת ה' לשמואל שלא התנבא מתחלה ולא שפע עליו השפע אלא שנגלה עליו קול כקול מורגש ולא השיג בזה יותר אבל אחר כך שפע עליו השפע והכיר והשיג הנבואה בדרכיה. וכן מראת הסנה למשה בתחלה לא נגלה לו אלא כמורגשות וראה הסנה בוער באש והקב"ה קראו כקולו של אביו אך אחר כך שפע עליו השפע והשיג הנבואה לאמתה

Summary: A prophet can get a prophecy and not recognize it, and mistake it for his own physical senses.  **This is what happened with Shmuel** - he mistook the voice for nothing more than a voice.

3:4:4:

> והנה יצטרכו למלמד ומדריך עד עמדם על בוריה של הנבואה בשלימות

Acquiring prophetic understanding requires a teacher and guide.

3:4:10:

> ומן המין הזה היו נביאי הבעל והאשרה שהנה היו משתדלים בזה עד שהיו מתדבקים בכחות האלה ומשיגים ידיעת קצת דברים שעל ידיהם היו מפתים המאמינים בם וכן מחדשים בכח זה נפלאות לאות על נבואתם וכמ"ש. ואמנם הם בעצמם היו יודעים שאין זה להם אלא מצד הטומאה מה שבחרו להם ולא היו חושבים בעצמם שהם נביאים אלא ברשעת לבבם היו עושים כן. אך גם למי שלא השתדל על זה היה אפשר שיקרה זה כמ"ש ועל כן היו צריכים המשתדלים לנבואה למלמד מובהק שילמדם כמ"ש ועל ידו היו נצולים. וכל זה עד שיגיעו למדריגת הנבואה באמת כי כיון שהגיעו לה כבר ראו ההפרש הגדול והכירוהו ואי אפשר להם עוד שיסתפקו בזה כלל

Summary: False prophets intentionally receive some power or knowledge from evil forces.  However, someone who is not properly versed in true prophecy can make an error and believe they are receiving true prophecy when they are actually not.  Therefore, a prophet needs to strive for prophecy under instruction of a guide.

Note that Eli actually instructed Shmuel to realize that it was Hashem speaing to him:

Shmuel 1 3:8-9

> ח וַיֹּסֶף יְהוָה קְרֹא-שְׁמוּאֵל, בַּשְּׁלִישִׁת, וַיָּקָם וַיֵּלֶךְ אֶל-עֵלִי, וַיֹּאמֶר הִנְנִי כִּי קָרָאתָ לִי; וַיָּבֶן עֵלִי, כִּי יְהוָה קֹרֵא לַנָּעַר.  ט וַיֹּאמֶר עֵלִי לִשְׁמוּאֵל, לֵךְ שְׁכָב, וְהָיָה אִם-יִקְרָא אֵלֶיךָ, וְאָמַרְתָּ דַּבֵּר יְהוָה כִּי שֹׁמֵעַ עַבְדֶּךָ; וַיֵּלֶךְ שְׁמוּאֵל, וַיִּשְׁכַּב בִּמְקוֹמוֹ

Summary: Eli realized it was Hashem speaking to him.  Eli told him, if you hear the voice again, respond and say "Speak Hashem for I am listening."